# Plone site: How do I get special characters to display properly on my plone page?

Tags: python, character, plone

I have a function in a view class of my content type that returns a dictionary.  The dictionary contains values retrieved from a mysql backend database (uses UTF-8 encoding).

One of the fields contains a special character (a combined with e), but renders as a "diamond with a question mark".

Here is how I build the dictionary I return in the function:

```
assetDetails = Session.execute("CALL getAssetDetails("+self.assetID+");").fetchone()
return dict(assetID=assetDetails[0],
            gpclAssetID=assetDetails[1],
            assetType=assetDetails[2],
            assetDescription=assetDetails[3],
            supplierName=assetDetails[4],
            model=assetDetails[5],
            serialNumber=assetDetails[6],
            status=assetDetails[7],
            location=assetDetails[8],
            options=assetDetails[9])
```

In my template file, the html tag is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
     xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
     xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
     xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"
     lang="en"
     metal:use-macro="context/main_template/macros/master"
  i18n:domain="gpcl.assets">
```

I show the information in this div:

```
<div tal:define="asset view/getAssetDetails">
    <div tal:content="asset/assetID"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/gpclAssetID"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/assetType"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/assetDescription"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/supplierName"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/model"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/serialNumber"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/status"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/location"></div>
    <div tal:content="asset/options"></div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so that special characters will display properly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'd convert your data to unicode to be on the safe side:

```
from Products.CMFPlone.utils import safe_unicode
...
return dict(assetID=safe_unicode(assetDetails[0]),
            gpclAssetID=safe_unicode(assetDetails[1]),
            assetType=safe_unicode(assetDetails[2]),
...
```

safe_unicode by default uses 'uft-8' but can be told to use a different character set for decoding your string: `safe_unicode('some text', 'latin-1')`

Answer (score 2):

If your strings are **really** 8 bit strings in UTF-8 encoding, you can simply use the Python `.decode` function.

```
<div tal:define="asset view/getAssetDetails">
   <div tal:content="python:asset.assetID.decode('utf-8')"></div>
...
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html for more.

Comment: Thanks for you response!  I appreciate it.
For some reason that was not working for me.

I double checked my database, phpmyadmin stated that the characterset was UTF-8.  However, your answer and the other answer did give me an idea to use based on something I found:
.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf8')
That's probably not as efficient as your answer, but I think its probable my database really isn't UTF-8?

Thanks again!